# Azure function Http trigger Ad authentication Asp.net core 3.1

Tags: azure-functions, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-http-trigger

I have created Rest Api with Azure function HttpTriggers along with swagger-UI (.net core 3.1, function V3) which is part of another Https trigger in the same project (total two triggers in different class files under same function project). Now I have enabled Azure Ad authentication from portal and that is working good on triggers.

Now the issue starts – I want to see the swagger UI when ever user requests with URL(http://localhost:7071/api/Swagger/ui) on the browser. Since the AD authentication enabled on function level, I am not able to see the Swagger-UI directly.
Are there any ways to enable Ad auth for only on one trigger? (not looking for function key auth). Or Any bypass mechansim that can configured for Swagger-UI trigger?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, the authentication options available for Azure Functions via the portal are either on for all endpoints of off entirely.

You can achieve the behaviour your after by authenticating tokens in your app instead of delegating that responsibility to Azure.